# How to add a circle after each button click android?

Tags: java, android, xml, button, canvas

I am trying to add a circle after each button click to the same screen. I haven't implemented the other button code yet but its supposed to clear the screen. The circles are supposed to be in a random position/size/color. I only have the first circle printed when i click the button. If i click it again my app closes. I haven't added the random location/size yet but i don't know how to make each button click show another circle on the screen. My code is below.

```
package com.example.randomcircles;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class DisplayRandomCircles extends Activity
{
DrawCircle c;
Canvas d;
FrameLayout f1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_random_circles);
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    c = new DrawCircle(getApplicationContext());
    d = new Canvas();
    f1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);

}
@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
public void doit(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case (R.id.btn1):
            f1.addView(c);
            break;

        case (R.id.btn2):
            break;
    }
}
}
```

my draw circle code

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawCircle extends View
{
public DrawCircle(Context con)
{
    super(con);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c)
{
    int min = 0, max = 200;
    int num = min + (int)(Math.random()*max);
    super.onDraw(c);
    Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p.setStrokeWidth(100);
    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    c.drawCircle(num, num, num, p);
    invalidate();
}
}
```

my layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".75"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:onClick="doit"
        android:text="@string/Circle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:onClick="doit"
        android:text="@string/Clear" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use random to get location, and create a method `addCircle`

Comment: do you want to draw **one** circle or do you want to add a **new** circle when that button is pressed?

Comment: I want to add a new circle every time I click the circle button

Answer (score 0):

While there are many ways of doing this, I'd like to show two ways of doing this:

Simplest way:

Use a list/array of DrawCircle elements in your activity, remove the property "c" and the code to initialize it in onCreate and modify doit() as shown below:

```
case (R.id.btn1):
  DrawCircle c = new DrawCircle(getApplicationContext());
  circleList.add(c);
  f1.addView(c);
  break;
```

The way I'd recommend the most:

1. Maintain two arrays/lists (or you can simply use a single hashmap) in DrawCircle:

   - One containing the list of circle centers
   - The other containing the list of diameters/radii.
2. In onDraw() add code to iterate through these lists and draw circles accordingly.
3. And modify the button click code to add random values to these two lists (either by calling a method such as addCircle() in DrawCircle (which I'd recommend) or by making those two lists public and adding to them directly)

Hope this helps.